# Como pasar un selected value a otro form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un problema al querer pasar un selected value a otro form como seria ? Si alguien me puede dar un ejemplo se lo agradeceria

Comment: aqui tienes https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/pass-data-from-one-form-to-other-using-properties-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el constructor. En el form 1 asignas tu `selectedValue` a una variable. Imagino que quieres pasarlo al presionar un botón,

**form 1:**

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string valor = combobox1.selectedValue.ToString();
    //instancias el form2 y le pasas tu variable 
    Form2 form2 = new Form2(valor) { Owner = this };
    form2.Show();
}
```

Y en el Form2:

```
public partial class Form2
{    
    private string _variable = null;
    
    public Form2()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(string variableForm1) : this()
    {
       _variable = variableForm1;
    }

    private void Form2_Load()
    {
      //y cuando cargue el form lo muestras
      label1.Text = _variable;
    }
}
```